# How to disable lbvirt network DNS

Tags: libvirt, dnsmasq

Is there a way to disable DNS in libvirt network? I want to have custom configured dnsmasq for local DNS caching but libvirt's dnsmasq holds 53 port.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a different type of network. On `<bridge>` networks, libvirt will always start dnsmasq. You can define your bridge manually and then use a `<forward mode="bridge">` network.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602797/how-to-force-libvirt-to-use-the-host-dnsmasq-service